# C++: Application architecture with API

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

My application it's C++ service. And I need to add API for it. I consider that it will be XML/JSON RPC based API. How should I design a program for reusing existing code base and provide API.

I see following options:

1. My application will work via RPC layer. Seems that it's bad option due to low performance;
2. Before starting of service I will fork it and run my application in the first process and RPC server in the second; Seems ok, but how to restart RPC server in this case?
3. I guess there is a well known pattern for such issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use a web server?  How about developing a REST API?  Maybe somebody can post some guidance for this type of scenario...

Comment: Yes, I can. But how does it help me? The problem is that I want to use common code for API (RPC/REST or what ever) - it a separate process as I understand - and my service that is also separate process.

Comment: Follow up on [the FastCGI concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI#Web_Servers_that_implement_FastCGI), which might be what you're looking for, or maybe give you some other ideas.

Comment: It's what I need. Thanks. Please make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a web server, then [the FastCGI concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI#Web_Servers_that_implement_FastCGI) might be what you're looking for.  One of the main duties of FastCGI is to allow you to put on a public API (from the web server) that internally calls the "real" application, in your case the resident C++ service.  So all work is done at the web server to create the public API using any technology you wish, and little or no code changes done in your C++ service.